# regex to split string with option stubstrings, into three

Tags: java, regex

I have asked a few regex related questions on here, and am learning a lot from the answers, but every now and then, I hit something that just stumps me.  This is one of those times!

I have a load of strings (all of which are single line), that I want to break up into three parts. However, some of the parts are optional.

To simplify this example, I will use people's names. Lets assume I have the following names

```
Mr Homer Simpson
Mrs Marge Simpson Esq
Mr Homer Simpson Junior Esq
Bart Simpson
Lisa Simpson Esq
Maggie Simpson Junior Esq
```

Using a replace function , I would want to separate these into Prefix, Name and Suffix. With the list above, I would expect to see

```
"Mr"    "Homer Simpson"    ""
"Mrs"   "Marge Simpson"    "Esq"
"Mr"    "Homer Simpson"    "Junior Esq"
""      "Bart Simpson"     ""
""      "Lisa Simpson"     "Esq"
""      "Maggie Simpson"   "Junior Esq"
```

The closest I can get is the following, which obviously is way off

((Mr|Mrs)\s)?(.*?)((Senior|Junior)?(?:\sEsq)?)

Can anyone assist?

Thanks

Comment: Y'know, I might have answered my own question here. Is the following correct? ^(Mr(?:s)*\s)?(.*?)(Junior(\sEsq)?|Senior(\sEsq)?|Esq|$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it looks like you might have answered you own question i had already started having ago:

```
^(Mrs?)?\s?(\w+\s\w+)\s((Junior|Senior)?\s?Esq)?
```

The above assumes that names will always be two words.

Example execution: http://regexr.com?387u1